# Can't understand why basic algorithm outputs 0, 4, 12, and 10 when N=2

Tags: c, algorithm

I recently started a course on the C language as a way to get a good fundamental understanding of programming. I reached a part in the course where it describes an algorithm. The steps it lists are:

> Given a non-negative integer N: (I used 2 as my integer)
> Make a variable called x, set it equal to (N+2)
> Count from 0 to N (include both ends), and for each number (call it "i") that you count:
>   Write down the value of (x * i)
>   Update x to be equal to (x + i * N)
> When you finish counting, write down the value of x.

I've tried following the steps logically but I'm somehow not ending up with the correct outputs of: 0, 4, 12 and 10 so I must have some fundamental misunderstanding of the instructions. If someone could break down how to follow those steps and tell me how the algorithm arrives at those outputs in a verbal manner I would really appreciate it.

Edit: I see how the first two outputs make sense (0 and 4) because 4 times 0 is 0 and 4 times 1 is 4 but I dont see how the third output is 12, as 4 times 3 is 12 and the next number in the sequence (i) counting from 0 to 2 is 2 and 4 times 2 is 8. I also don't see how x=10 at the end. Is there some way that these following two things interact that I'm not aware of that produces the final value of x? (the counting from 0 to 2; multiplying by x and the other thing, calculating x + i * n) I know what the outputs are supposed to be because the course tells you what you should've arrived at.

Thank you,
-Michael

Comment: Please make a responsible example, with some code!

Comment: Burden of working it out is on you. Show what you've tried and perhaps we can help you spot the error in reasoning.

Comment: @GonçaloBastos. Pseudo code or manual calculation is probably fine

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, bet he should try something and post here, what he has tried, so we can help him! We should not do all the job!

Comment: I'd assume you understand how to calculate manually. Because you know this (`correct outputs of: 0, 4, 12 and 10`). Make sure your code followed the exact logic in the question. There's nothing to break down or special on the question since the question is pretty clear, as long as you understand what it means.

Answer (score 3):

> Given a non-negative integer N: (I used 2 as my integer) Make a
> variable called x,

```
int n = 2;
int x;
```

> set it equal to (N+2)

```
x = n+2;
```

> Count from 0 to N (include both ends), and for each number (call it
> "i") that you count:

```
int i; 
for(i=0; i<=n; i++) {
```

> Write down the value of (x * i)

```
   printf("x * i = %d\n", x*i);
```

> Update x to be equal to (x + i * N)

```
   x = x + i * n;
```

> When you finish counting, write down the value of x.

```
}
printf("x = %d\n", x);
```

Your description can be translated almost word-for-word to C (or to most programming languages). What steps have you "followed logically", and where do they deviate from this translation? If you copy and paste the above fragments into a file, you can see that the output is indeed correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n = 2;
    int x;
    x = n+2;
    int i; 
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++) { 
       printf("x * i = %d\n", x*i);
       x = x + i * n;
    }
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
}
```

output:

```
x * i = 0
x * i = 4
x * i = 12
x = 10
```